# ProgressDialog doesn't show the real progress of fetching information from a web server

Tags: android, progressdialog

I transferred my code of fetching some information into an Async class, it is to minimize the buffering and avoid the possibility of 'not responding', or worse crashing of my application.

Now, I want to show a ProgressDialog, and it should be set to 'not cancelable' to avoid users of interrupting the connection.

But I am a little confused if my ProgressDialog really show the progress of what actually happens in my application (during the fetching of information from an online server). Because on my emulator, my application pauses (for about 2 seconds), and then shows the ProgressDialog, and then immediately shows the result of the 'fetching'.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks. Here's my code.

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    new retrieveOnline().execute();
}

private class retrieveOnline extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void>
{
    protected void onPreExecute ()
    {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog (FirstScreen.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused)
    {
        runOnUiThread (new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httppost = new HttpPost("http://mysite.com/database/login.php");
                stringEmail = etEmail.getText().toString();
                stringPassword = etPassword.getText().toString();

                try 
                {
                    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringEmail", stringEmail));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringPassword", stringPassword));

                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()== 200)
                    {
                        entity = response.getEntity();
                        if(entity != null)
                        {   
                            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));

                            String errorEmail = jsonResponse.getString("errorEmail");
                            if (errorEmail != "")
                            {
                                tvEmailError.setText(errorEmail);
                            }else{}

                            String errorPassword = jsonResponse.getString("errorPassword");
                            if (errorPassword != "")
                            {
                                tvPasswordError.setText(errorPassword);
                            }else{}

                            String inactiveAccount = jsonResponse.getString("inactiveAccount");
                            if (inactiveAccount.length() != 0)
                            {                       
                                AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(FirstScreen.this).create();
                                alert.setCancelable(false);
                                alert.setMessage("Your account is currently inactive and unusable." + "\nDo you want to send an account activation message to your email now?");
                                alert.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                {   
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                                    {
                                        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                        httppost = new HttpPost("http://mysite.com/database/activate2.php");
                                        stringEmail = etEmail.getText().toString();
                                        stringPassword = etPassword.getText().toString();

                                        try
                                        {
                                            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringEmail", stringEmail));
                                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringPassword", stringPassword));

                                            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                                            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                                            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()== 200)
                                            {
                                                entity = response.getEntity();
                                                if(entity != null)
                                                {
                                                    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                                                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));

                                                    String successActivation = jsonResponse.getString("successActivation");
                                                    if (successActivation.length() != 0)
                                                    {
                                                        //Progress Dialog here.
                                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "We successfully sent an activation message to your email account. Try to log in again after activating your account.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, we are unable to reach your email account.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }   
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception e)
                                        {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection to the server is lost. Please check your internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                alert.setButton2("Not now", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                {   
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                                    {
                                        AlertDialog alert2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(FirstScreen.this).create();
                                        alert2.setCancelable(false);
                                        alert2.setMessage("Exit FindDroid?");
                                        alert2.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                        {   
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                                            {
                                                finish();
                                            }
                                        });
                                        alert2.setButton2("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                        {   
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                                            {
                                                //Do nothing
                                            }
                                        });
                                        alert2.show();
                                    }
                                });
                                alert.show();
                            }else{}

                            if ((errorEmail.length()==0) && (errorPassword.length()==0)&& (inactiveAccount.length()==0))
                            {                       
                                String dbEmail = jsonResponse.getString("dbEmail");
                                String dbPassword = jsonResponse.getString("dbPassword");
                                //---Store dbEmail and dbPassword to SharedPreferences---//
                                //-------------------------------------------------------//
                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Construction.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                                finish();
                            }

                        }//if (entity!=null)..      
                    }//if response()...
                }//try..
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection to the server is lost. Please check your internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }   

            }
        });

        return (null);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute (Void unused)
    {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I am making a log in activity, and it's getting the registered users information from an online server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, call publishProgress from `doInBackground` with an integer to pass to `pDialog.setProgress(int)`  Alter the `AsyncTask` signature to pass the integer `<Void, Integer, Void>`  You'll want to normalize that progress integer between 0-10000 before passing to `onProgressUpdate`  This can be done when loading an image or a large amount of data from the web by loop through bytes or lines, reading in chunks, and passing progress update as you go.

Another thing you need to modify, is you CANNOT access/modify/touch-in-any-way objects in the UI during `doInBackground`  You'll need to move things like `alert.show()` Toast and I beleive the Activity methods also (ie. `finish()`) to the `postExecute` method.

Comment: Oh, I see. But how will I do it? Can you please guide me?
Do I only need to put some incrementation? And not pass in some integer value?

Comment: 0 to 10,000 (100%).  You'll have to decide what percentage of progress you've made in your task (completely relies on what you're doing), convert that percentage to the range 0-10000 and pass that to progressUpdate().  For example if I'm downloading bytes of an image, I might do something like this: progressUpdate((int)((float)bytesDownloaded/(float)totalBytes)*10000f)));

Comment: Sir, can you explain more or give me some examples? I really don't know what I am going to do.

Comment: But my application is different from the downloading stuff.
How will I pass in an integer value if the process in my doInBackground is not containing an integer value?

Comment: I am only making a log in and sign up activities.. I don't have some integers to pass in. How will I do this?

Comment: I see it looks like you are already using an indeterminate progress bar which is good for just showing that something is processing in the background when you don't have a distinct percentage of progress.  With the indeterminate progress bar you don't need to use the setProgress() method of the ProgressDialog and hence don't really need to implement onProgressUpdate of AsyncTask.

Comment: You really should read through and understand the AsyncTask documentation:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html   You can't just create a retrieveOnline object and .execute it more than once, you'll get errors.  You should just create a new one and execute in your onClick

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so what you have here is an AsyncTask that immediately creates a runnable that runs on the UI thread, completely defeating the purpose of the AsyncTask.  Get rid of the runOnUIThread, do all the processing in the background call and use the OnProgressUpdate and OnPostExecute to update the UI.  Also ready the API documentation here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

The ProgressDialog doesn't automatically update, you need to update it in the OnProgressUpdate call from your AsyncTask.

Comment: How will I update the progressDialog? Do I need to pass in an integer value? Please help me.

Comment: ready->read. SO won't let me fix the typo unless I change at least 6 characters...

Comment: If you look at the section called Usage in the documentation I linked it shows you what to do.  You call publishProgress in the doBackground which will call OnProgressUpdate in the UI thread so you can update the ProgressDialog or any other UI element you want to.  Then after you exit the doInBackground it will call onPostExecute on the UI thread so you can dismiss the progressdialog and also update the UI with any remaining data.

Comment: I think the code that is in the link that you have given me is very different from what I am having now.. I don't have a precise integer value to increment. Please guide me.

Comment: Do I only need to call publishProgress in the doInBackground? Or do I still have to pass in an integer value like the count variable from the example that you gave me. Sorry, but I am a newbie in android programming. Thanks.